# How to execute a line of App Scripts code for creating a trigger only once?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to execute a line of App Scripts code for creating a trigger only once as a bound scripts while opening the Google spreadsheet first time or creating it as a copy of another spreadsheet so that I can do a series of process using the trigger. Then never want to execute it again. Can be self destroyed. How to do that?

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("createTemplate2").forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
```

Comment: Why not bind it to a menu button?

Comment: Related: [installing a trigger by script keeps adding triggers to template sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62708340/1595451)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Explanation:**

I would advice you to use a [Custom Menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) with two buttons:

- `Add Trigger` will add a new trigger for `createTemplate2`
- `Remove Trigger` will remove the trigger/s for `createTemplate2`

In this way, you have the flexibility to control when you want to `create` or `destroy` the trigger according to your needs.

---

### **Solution:**

Copy & Paste the following code to the script editor, save the changes, refresh the spreadsheet file and you will be able to see the custom menu at the top bar.

```
function addTrigger() {
  
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("createTemplate2").forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
 }

function createTemplate2(){
// code here
}


function removeTrigger(){
  
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
triggers.forEach(tr=>{                
   if (tr.getHandlerFunction() == "createTemplate2")
  { ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(tr) }               
 }); 

}


function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Macros')
  .addItem('Add Trigger', 'addTrigger')
  .addItem('Remove Trigger', 'removeTrigger')
  .addToUi();
}
```

[image: custom menu]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to automatically create an installable trigger when spreadsheet is opened if the trigger doesn't already exist.

This is not possible without previously creating an installable on open trigger. Considering this it's very likely that the best way to proceed is to create the trigger manually or from a custom menu.